Docking station not working on ubuntu but works on windows
I've got a v7 docking station. The monitor connected to it doesn't seem to be recognised on Ubuntu (24.04). On windows it works fine.
I have a fairly recent Asus miniPC (PN63-S1) that seems to not have thunderbolt support on the USB outlets.
but as i said - it works on Windows so I assume i am missing something from my Ubuntu to get it working.
I have installed the displaylink driver. But perhaps there is a need to verify it is installed correctly.
Maybe someone has any clues? Thank you.
